# Wordpress. Why instead of a template, a 404 page is loaded?

Tags: wordpress

I created a taxonomy template, but when I go to the taxon page, the 404 page is loaded. I can’t understand why Wordpress thinks that there is no such page (it doesn’t load at least the archive page or index)

```
register_taxonomy('hotel', array('travel'), $args);
```

[image: editor scrin]

[image: browser scrin]

Comment: Did you flush the permalinks?

Comment: Right, I forgot about that part. Thanks, everything works as it should!

Comment: Okayy, Great :)